# Textarea Centers First Line Of Text And I Want It To Be Left-Aligned

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

I've got a simple textarea in a form and for some reason when I click in the textarea to begin to type, it centers the first line. I can hit backspace until it lines up at the start of textarea but I don't know why it's doing that. I've Googled and can't seem to find a reason why it would do this. Here is my jsfiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cVkn/

I've tried text-align:left in numerous places (inline HTML and CSS) and it doesn't seem to change anything. It seems like it should be a simple fix, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It isn't centred, it just has a default value of a series of space characters.

Put `</textarea>` immediately after the start tag instead of filling it with whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The default content of a text area is the content between its tags. Your source has something like:

```
        <textarea name="bio">
        </textarea>
```

so the initial value of the text area is the newline and the spaces used for indentation – the characters you can backspace over.

To get rid of them, close the tag immediately:

```
<textarea name="bio"></textarea>
```

Aside: the kind of form layout you're going for should probably be done using tables – at least until the various shiny new CSS3 layouts are better supported. Your avoiding them actually made the code less readable what with all the `<br/>`s.

Comment: While the excessive line breaks aren't good style, tables are not the solution.

Comment: @Quentin: I'm not aware of any other way, in widely-supported CSS, to achieve a grid-based layout without having to accept some constraints on the solution. (Like absolute widths or heights of columns / rows.) As unfortunate as that is, this is an area where tables seem to be the only (ugly) solution.

Comment: Yeah I looked into that, I know it's pretty awful looking code with all of the '<br />'s but I've lately been trying to avoid using tables altogether. I reassigned the line-height of the '<br />' in the CSS and so that's why there are so many of them. I was using them to be real specific about my positioning.

Comment: @MxmastaMills: For me the main reason for avoiding tables is because they add superfluous levels of nesting which makes the code harder to read, rather than having a dogmatic stance on semantic HTML. So in my book, replacing something hard to read with something even harder to read that doesn't work better is not the right thing to do. (The jsfiddle showed the form fields below the lower edge of the result area, and it took me a while to figure out they're really there.)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that on the jsfiddle (I had to drag the window out to get them to line up properly). In the context of the site I'm building, everything stays in the right place because it's all div'ed out so the '<br />'s have actually allowed me to line up the labels right where I want them (as opposed to what happened on the jsfiddle). I do understand what you're saying though and I've got a good amount of nested div's already on my site...